# Is there an algorithm for finding a geometric realization of a finite abstract simplicial complex

Tags: geometry, polytopes, simplicial-complex

I have a $d$-dimensional finite abstract simplicial complex (ASC); that is I have a sequence of incidence matrices that define the complex. I know that any such ASC can be embedded in ${\mathbb R}^N$ for $N$ approximately the number of vertices. I'm interested in embeddings in ${\mathbb R}^d$ (or ${\mathbb R}^{d+1,d}$). Is there an algorithm to find such an embedding or determine if it doesn't exist?

Following the suggestion in the comments I'm adding a concrete example of what I mean by incidence matrices. The complex here corresponds to the 3d associahedron (of type A) :

```
C[1] is 1x9 matrix
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]

C[2] is 9x21 matrix
[[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1]]

C[3] is 21x14 matrix
[[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]]

C[4] is 14x1 matrix
[[1],
[1],
[1],
[1],
[1],
[1],
[1],
[1],
[1],
[1],
[1],
[1],
[1],
[1]]
```

Comment: Your post has close votes (not by me) almost certainly because you haven't given enough information about the context of your problem and what you have tried. You also need to explain what you mean by a sequence of incidence matrices that define the complex. ...

Comment: ... for a specific finite abstract simplicial complex with $n$ vertices, we know that it can be embedded in $\Bbb{R}^n$, so your problem reduces to a problem in real arithmetic over $n$ variables and hence is decidable.

Comment: @RobArthan I added an example of incidence matrices in the body of the question; hopefully that makes things more clear

Comment: It makes things a bit clearer. I'd have to think a bit about whether defining which $n$-simplices are adjacent to which $n+1$ simplices fully defines the complex. But, in any case, the suggested answer in my earlier comment stands, you are asking about the existence of a set of points in $\Bbb{R}^d$ (or whatever) that satisfy a given set of formulas in the language of real arithmetic. That is a decidable problem.